# Cant read DateTime from DatePicker using Dispatcher.Invoke C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some Windows Framework Presentation application.

All action done by background worker. I'm trying to get selected date.

```
DateTime StartDate = DateTime.MinValue;
StartOfferDatePicker.Dispatcher.Invoke(
    new Action(delegate()
    {
        StartDate = StartOfferDatePicker.GetValue(DatePicker.SelectedDateProperty);
    }
));
```

I get the error `Can not imlicitly convert an 'object' to System.DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

Well no... the declared return type of [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.getvalue.aspx) is just `object`. If the value is *actually* a `DateTime` you should just be able to cast:

```
StartDate = (DateTime) StartOfferDatePicker.GetValue(DatePicker.SelectedDateProperty);
```

Note that this has nothing to do with `Dispatcher.Invoke`. You'd see the exact same problem if you had the same code in an event handler.

However, it might be simpler just to use the [`SelectedDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddate.aspx) property:

```
StartDate = StartOfferDatePicker.SelectedDate.Value;
```

The `.Value` part is because `SelectedDate` is of type `Nullable<DateTime>`. Of course this will go bang if no date has been selected - you should think about how you want to handle that. (Perhaps your `StartDate` variable should *also* be a `Nullable<DateTime>`.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use   `StartDate = StartOfferDatePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Date;`